# Teradata "Period" data type triggering error

Tags: sql, types, teradata, period

I just downloaded the TDExpress VM, and when I try to create tables with a column that has a period data type (for example period(date)), I get an error that says "an index is not supported by the period column"...however according to 
[this link](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/PeriodTypeOverview.html) it is supported, and the correct syntax.

I get the same error if i include the precision or not (in the case of period(time)).

edit : DDL-

CREATE TABLE test (
value1 int null,
timePer period(date) null
);

Comment: Please post your DDL.

Comment: Did you create a table with a Period as first column and didn't specify the Primary Index? Then it defaults to the first column and Period's can't be indexed.

Comment: I didnt specify a primary index but it was after an int. It was something like:

CREATE TABLE test (
value1 integer null,
timePer period(date) null
)

Comment: Your Create looks fine, this should run without error.